# Website Redirects

Tags: redirects

I've been having a bit of an issue today. I run Gematsu.com. At first I thought the site has been going slow all day due to the amount of hits we've been getting the past couple days. But then I realized we'd received even less today, so something wasn't adding up.

I ran a check on a website testing site.Turns out I have a bunch of redirects from URLs that I've never heard of. I don't know if they're what's slowing the site down, but I can tell you the site wasn't taking a minute to load yesterday.

I tried removing my advertising to see if it was anything on their end, but I still got largely the same results.

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at your waterfall report. I do not see a minute, but I do see a reasonably slow 12.73 second download that can be fixed. However, in your history, I see another story. Here it appears that your HTML is not the problem so much as the resources.

This is an extremely high number of requests- total 303. Most people freak out at 70 or 90. Most of the JavaScript does seems to load okay. I am not too worried about the 302 redirects as a rule. I am worried about the number of requests.

I will get back to the URL situation in a minute.

The primary site problems I think I see are fat images and a 6 second download of your HTML.

Your HTML should not take 6 seconds to download. There is something wrong here. Check your code and lean it out. It may be okay. I am saying just look at it. Also check to see if you are having any latency issues. Your response time is too long. Sometimes this can be a network problem. Reboot your router if you have one. Otherwise, I am not sure what to say on this at this point. You may need to reboot your system too- but I would wait till I finished all the work I was going to do. You may need to call your host if the reboots do not work. But this would be that last issue in the list I would bird-dog.

I recently thinned out my images because they were too fat. I used SmallerAnimals ThumbNailer to do this. Here is the link: http://www.smalleranimals.com/thumb.htm You can download it and use the trial version for a period. I highly recommend this software! Hell- it is only $15! These guys really really really (did I say really?) know what they are doing when it comes to images. I have used this software for 10-12 years and maybe more- I cannot remember. I did not change the image quality, the DPI, the image size or anything. I made a copy of my images directory and told it to go to town. The result was much smaller files. About 1/4 if I remember right. This is a fairly technical tool so you may want to fiddle around a bit and RTM for sure. DO NOT work on the live directory even when you know what you are doing.

About the URLs. I do not know what to say. I do not know what advertising company(s) you are using, but it seems to be a lot of JavaScript requests. Check with the ad companies that you use and see what URLs you should see. If there should not be 303 requests, then I suggest the following.

Scan the entire file system with a GOOD anti-virus including rootkit just to be sure. I know there are some hacks out there that load a bunch of cr@p that you may not be aware of. It can all be ad related too. It may be that your system was compromised and it is loading things you do not want. I would do this quickly too. If your system is compromised, it may be blacklisted quickly. I checked http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx and you are clear as of now.